# How to delete files from one folder based on another folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, file-management

I have a folder with JPGs that are "good" ones. I then have a folder with ALL of the JPGs + their RAW file. How can I delete the JPG+RAW files based on the files in the good folder?

Even if there's an app that could do that it would be great!

Comment: Could you give a small example of the files in the good folder and one of the one in the all folder and which ones you wish to delete.

Comment: `273: IMG_0896.jpg`
`274: IMG_0907.jpg`
`275: IMG_0908.jpg`
`276: IMG_0910.jpg`
`277: IMG_0912.jpg`
`278: IMG_0913.jpg`
`279: IMG_0915.jpg`
`281: IMG_0920.jpg`
`

And in the other folder the same except .jpg and .CR2. I am trying to remove but keep the ones I want to remain. I think I need to think about this the other way; Take list of filenames, copy the filename.jpg & filename.cr2 to another folder, then delete the other folder.

Comment: You want to delete all the files that don't exist in the good folder or the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

here's a simple solution, run the commands in `Powershell`, remember to take a backup first!

First get the list of files in the first directory (the good ones)
0: `$goodfiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\DBB\Pictures\GoodPics -Name)`
*Change the path with the one you want!*
(Note: for your convenience, you can also use the "Pattern" parameter here, if the good folder has non-jpeg files)

Then, switch to the directory you want to filter:
1: `cd C:\Users\DBB\Pictures\UnfilteredPics`
*Change the path with the one you want!*

Remove the same-named items:
2: `foreach ($f in $goodfiles) {rm -f $f}`

Remove the corresponding RAW files (if you wish):
3: `foreach ($f in $goodfiles) {rm -f $f.replace('.jpg', '.raw')}`

---

Explanation:

0. Get a list of the good files - just their names (-Name), store it in `$goodfiles`
1. Switch directory
2. Forcefully remove each file with the same name as any file in `$goodfiles` - forcefully (-f in rm) so that if it doesn't exist, there won't be an error
3. Remove files with corresponding extension as .RAW instead of .JPG (note that `1.jpg` good file will cause `1.raw` file to be removed, not `1.jpg.raw`)

---

Copyable, syntax-highlighted code:

```ps
# Get a list of the good files - just their names (-Name), store it in $goodfiles
$goodfiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\DBB\Pictures\GoodPics -Name)
# Switch directory
cd C:\Users\DBB\Pictures\UnfilteredPics
# Forcefully remove each file with the same name as any file in $goodfiles - forcefully (-f in rm) so that if it doesn't exist, there won't be an error
foreach ($f in $goodfiles) {rm -f $f}
# Remove files with corresponding extension as .RAW instead of .JPG (note that 1.jpg good file will cause 1.raw file to be removed, not 1.jpg.raw)
foreach ($f in $goodfiles) {rm -f $f.replace('.jpg', '.raw')}
```